# ANTLR String interpolation

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to write an ANTLR grammar that parses string interpolation expressions such as:

```
my.greeting = "hello ${your.name}"
```

The error I get is:

```
line 1:31 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:34 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
```

[image: Output from ANTLR IntelliJ Plugin]

MyParser.g4:

```
parser grammar MyParser;

options { tokenVocab=MyLexer; }

program: variable EQ expression EOF;
expression: (string | variable);
variable: (VAR DOT)? VAR;
string: (STRING_SEGMENT_END expression)* STRING_END;
```

MyLexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;

START_STR: '"' -> more, pushMode(STRING_MODE) ;
VAR: (UPPERCASE|LOWERCASE) ANY_CHAR*;
EQ: '=';
DOT: '.';

WHITE_SPACE: (SPACE | NEW_LINE | TAB)+ -> skip;

fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
fragment LOWERCASE: 'a'..'z';
fragment UPPERCASE: 'A'..'Z';
fragment ANY_CHAR: LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | DIGIT;
fragment NEW_LINE: '\n' | '\r' | '\r\n';
fragment SPACE: ' ';
fragment TAB: '\t';

mode INTERPOLATION_MODE;

STRING_SEGMENT_START: '}' -> more, popMode;

mode STRING_MODE;

STRING_END: '"' -> popMode;
STRING_SEGMENT_END: '${' -> pushMode(INTERPOLATION_MODE);
TEXT : ~["$]+ -> more ;
```

Expressions like the following work fine:

```
my.greeting = "hello"
my.greeting = "hello ${} world"
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
mode INTERPOLATION_MODE;

STRING_SEGMENT_START: '}' -> more, popMode;
I_VAR: (UPPERCASE|LOWERCASE) ANY_CHAR*;
I_DOT: '.';

...

variable: ((VAR|I_VAR) (DOT|I_DOT))? (VAR|I_VAR);
```

you could try:

```
mode INTERPOLATION_MODE;

STRING_SEGMENT_START: '}' -> more, popMode;
I_VAR: (UPPERCASE|LOWERCASE) ANY_CHAR* -> type(VAR);
I_DOT: '.' -> type(DOT);

...

variable: (VAR DOT)? VAR;
```

Comment: I realize this isn't an answer to your question, but more a remark (that doesn't fit in the comments) on your answer. So if this fixes it, I suggest you add this to  your own answer and accept that. I'll remove this answer then.

Comment: Thanks Bart.  I think yours is a great answer.  Much nicer than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've worked out (inspired by [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/81PVv9xLmP0)) that I need to define the default lexer rules again in the INTERPOLATION_MODE:

MyLexer.g4:

```
...
mode INTERPOLATION_MODE;

STRING_SEGMENT_START: '}' -> more, popMode;
I_VAR: (UPPERCASE|LOWERCASE) ANY_CHAR*;
I_DOT: '.';

...
```

MyParser.g4:

```
...
variable: ((VAR|I_VAR) (DOT|I_DOT))? (VAR|I_VAR);
...
```

[image: Output from IntelliJ ANTLR Plugin]

This seems overkill though, so still holding out for someone with a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

*String interpolation* also implemented in existing [C#](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp) and [PHP](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/php) grammars in official ANTLR grammars repository.