# String Interpolation in Antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar that uses modes to do string interpolation:
Something along the lines of:

```
lexer grammar Example;

//default mode tokens
LBRACE: '{' -> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE);
RBRACE: '}' -> popMode;

OPEN_STRING: '"' -> pushMode(STRING);
mode STRING;
ID_INTERPOLATION: '$' IDEN;
OPEN_EXPR_INTERPOLATION: '${' -> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE);
TEXT: '$' | (~[$\r\n])+;
CLOSE_STRING: '"' -> popMode;
```

```
parser grammar ExampleParser;
options {tokenVocab = Example;}

test: string* EOF;
string: OPEN_STRING string_part* CLOSE_STRING;
string_part: TEXT | ID_INTERPOLATION | OPEN_EXPR_INTERPOLATION expr RBRACE;


//more rules that use LBRACE and RBRACE
```

Now this works and tokenizes everything *mostly* how I want it, but it does have 2 flaws.

1. if the number of RBRACES goes too far, it can pop the first default mode which can glitch out the IDE, and does not just show an error.
2. The token for closing a block and closing interpolation is the same, so I cannot highlight them however I want. (this is the main one)

My IDE highlights based on tokens only, so this is a problem, I'd like to be able to highlight them differently. So basically I'd like a solution for this that makes the RBRACE a different token when it's in a string.

I'd prefer to do it without semantic predicates because I don't want to tie it down to a language, but if needed, I'm ok with it, I just might need a little more explanation because I haven't used them that much.

Comment: `The token for closing a block and closing interpolation is the same`: I don't understand, I see 2 different chars being used to "close" things: the `"` and `}`

Comment: Also, why have `LBRACE: '{'  -> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE)` and  `RBRACE: '}' -> popMode;` at all (the mode pushing and popping, that is)? Or have you tried to simplify the problem too much? In that case, please edit your question to resemble you original grammar more closely.

Comment: I was referring to a rule I didn't include in this code, I did oversimplify a bit, the reason I push mode with LBRACE is that every other place RBRACE is used is with conjunction with an LBRACE, so I don't want to accidentally pop the outermost mode. I want to make a distinction between every other time I use RBRACE (when it's used to encapsulate bits of code) and when I use it for interpolation. So a different token would be matched when going back to string mode.

Comment: I am popping RBRACE so that when you have done interpolation it goes back to string mode, so you can say the following:

`"x + 1 = ${x + 1}"`

Comment: I think what's confusing Bart is that you seem to have forgotten `-> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE)` on the `OPEN_EXPR_INTERPOLATION` rule. Anyway, I believe you can get what you want by adding actions that keep track of the nested `{}`s. Something like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53524929/149392), but you'd want to use a stack rather than a mere counter to keep track of when you're popping a `{}` and when a `${}`, so you can change the token type appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sepp2k for helping me solve my issue.

It's a bit of a hack but it does exactly what I need it to

I solved it by changing my popMode on RBRACE to be the following:

```
RBRACE: '}' {
    if(_modeStack.size() > 0) {
        popMode();
        if(_mode != DEFAULT_MODE) {
            setType(EXPR_INTERPOLATION);
        }
    }
};
```

I also changed my parser to be

```
string_part: TEXT | ID_INTERPOLATION | EXPR_INTERPOLATION expr EXPR_INTERPOLATION;
```

I know it's pretty hacky to change the token type under a specific circumstance, but it got the job done for me, so I'm gonna keep it unless I find a less hacky way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So I set out to implement an interpolated string parser with using only ANTLR code (no host language code blocks). I found that this works well, including nesting interpolated strings...

```
lexer grammar Lexer;

LeftBrace: '{';
RightBrace: '}' -> popMode;

Backtick: '`' -> pushMode(InterpolatedString);
Integer: [0-9]+;
Plus: '+';

mode InterpolatedString;

EscapedLeftBrace: '\\{' -> type(Grapheme);
EscapedBacktick: '\\`' -> type(Grapheme);
ExprStart: '{' -> type(LeftBrace), pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE);
End: '`' -> type(Backtick), popMode;
Grapheme: ~('{' | '`');
```

```
parser grammar Parser;

options {
    tokenVocab = Lexer;
}

startRule: expression EOF;

interpolatedString: Backtick (Grapheme | interpolatedStringExpression)* Backtick;

interpolatedStringExpression: LeftBrace expression RightBrace;

expression
    : expression Plus expression
    | atom
    ;
    
atom: Integer | interpolatedString;
```

You can test it with input

```
`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`hello world`}`}`}`}`}`}`}`
```